# [B symbol in java bytecode

Tags: disassembly, java, byte-code

I looking at java bytecode and understand almost everything.

I saw the symbol `[B` on java bytecode.

What does it mean?

Comment: can you add a sample snippet to the question? Use the edit link below it.

Answer (score 2):

It means a byte array.

In the Java descriptor syntax, a `[` at the beginning means an array. There's a one letter code for each primitive type - B = Byte, C = Char, S = Short, Z = Boolean, I = Int, J = Long, F = Float, and D = Double. Object types are represented by L, followed by the classname, followed by a semicolon.

So for example, a `String[][][]` would have the descriptor `[[[Ljava/lang/String;`.